# Unable to Compile wxAgg, backend for wxpython to embed matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, wxpython, embed, wxwidgets

I am trying to complile wxAgg that I might embed matplotlib plots in wxpython. But, I am not able to compile it successfully. Is there any windows installer available?

The error i am getting is, 'wxUSE_ACTIVEX must be defined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are on Windows, for that I use this one 'matplotlib-1.4.0.win32-py2.7.exe' from http://matplotlib.org/downloads.html

Just ensure to use the installer which corresponds to the Python version you are using.

Comment: werner thanks for your reply, i suppose that, wxAgg should be seperately installed.  I have already installed matplotlib. Now, I am trying to embed matplotlib into wxpython which seems to require wxAgg as backend. Now, I am facing difficulties in installing wxAgg. I was wondering whether there exists a windows installer for wxAgg, for I could not compile wxAgg

Comment: @boon, I do use mpl together with wxPython and never installed wxAgg separately.

Comment: @boon, what happens if you do 'import matplotlib' 'matplotlib.use('WXAgg') at a Python prompt?

Comment: @boon, or you can test with this: http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_wx2.html

Comment: werner, 'import matplotlib' and 'matplotlib.use('WXAgg') are not throwing any error. But, when I run the example frrom, ' matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_wx2.html', I get the error, "No module named wxversion'

Comment: @boon, wxversion is an optional download to select a particular wxPython version at run time. just comment the line 'import wxversion' and the one after that.

Comment: Werner, I tried doing that, then I get the error, "ImportError:Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxversion, which was not found".

Comment: @boon, hhm, didn't remember that sorry.  So, easiest is to install wxversion.py to your site-packages folder you can get it from here: https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython/tree/master/wxversion

Comment: Thanks for the help, werner. I installed a latest version of wxpython and it solved the problem.